# Why does bazel fail with header not under the specified strip prefix

Tags: bazel

I am using bazel 3.7.2 (the same project works OK with bazel 3.3.1)

In my build file I use:

```
cc_library(
   name = "xft",
   hdrs = ["@nixpkgs_xft//:include"],                                                                                                         
   strip_include_prefix = "/external/nixpkgs_xft/include",
)
```

Running `bazel build target`, bazel complains:

```
BUILD:71:11: in cc_library rule //target:xft: header 'external/nixpkgs_xft/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h' is not under the specified strip prefix 'external/nixpkgs_xft/include'
```

Somehow bazel got a different understanding of a header's prefix... How is this supposed to work?

```
external/nixpkgs_xft/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h
external/nixpkgs_xft/include
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, the error message is really confusing. I looked through the code and found that there is a different thing compared to the prefix than the header file: the repository relative path is compared to the prefix (but the error message prints the "exec path").

Seems in newer Bazel, you do no longer need to include the `exernal/foo` part of the path, so this works:

```
cc_library(
    name = "xft",
    hdrs = ["@nixpkgs_xft//:include"],
    strip_include_prefix = "/include",
)
```

Comment: stackoverflow-driven-development insta saved me from hours of debugging, thankfully to you, good sir. In my case `strip_include_prefix = "/external/cista/file"` was giving error `... in cc_library rule //:cista: header 'external/cista/file/cista.h' is not under the specified strip prefix 'external/cista/file'`. I'm just wandering what code you was looking through? Code of bazel itself? :O

Comment: @Slaus yes, I was reading through the Bazel source code :-)